# Differentiation of $o(x^n)$

Tags: calculus

I was investigating the properties of $o(x^n)$ and found that under some circumstances its derivative is $o(x^{n-1})$, but under some other circumstances it is not true, like the function 
$$
x^3\sin \frac{1}{x} (x\neq 0); 0(x=0).
$$
What are the conditions for $o(x^n)’=o(x^{n-1})$ to hold?

Add: Could you provide some other examples of $f(x)$ such that $f(x)=o(x^n)$ for some $n$ but $f’(x)\neq o(x^{n-1})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that by definition

$$o(x^n)=\omega(x)\cdot x^n$$

with $\omega(x)\to 0$ therefore

$$\frac{d(o(x^n))}{dx}=\omega’(x)\cdot x^n+ \omega(x)\cdot nx^{n-1}=\left(\omega’(x)\cdot x+ n\omega(x)\right)\cdot x^{n-1}$$

therefore we need that $\exists \omega(x)$ differentiable such that

$$\omega’(x)\cdot x\to 0$$

Your example works indeed since

$$x^3\sin \frac{1}{x}=\frac{\sin \frac1x}{\frac 1x}\cdot x^2 =o(x^2)$$

with $\omega(x)=\frac{\sin \frac1x}{\frac 1x}$ and

$$\omega'(x)\cdot x=\frac{\sin \frac1x}{\frac 1x}-\cos \frac1x$$

Answer (score 3):

From the definition of $f(x) = o_{x\to a}(g(x))$, you have $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0.$$

This means that $$f(x) = \epsilon(x) g(x)$$ with some function $\epsilon$ so that  $\epsilon(x) \to 0$ when $x\to a$.

Back to your problem, let $f(x) = o(x^n)$. By the previous remark,

$$f(x) = \epsilon(x)x^n$$

with $\lim_{x\to 0} \epsilon(x)= 0$

From my understanding, to achieve the property you want, you need to know more about $\epsilon$ : in the general case, it may not be possible. The first condition you need is that $\epsilon$ is differentiable. Assuming this,

$$f'(x) = \epsilon'(x)x^n + nx^{n-1}\epsilon(x)$$

To have $f'(x) = o(x^{n-1})$, we must ensure that $\epsilon'(x)x^n = o(x^{n-1})$ itself, i.e. $x\epsilon'(x) \to 0$.

As a conclusion and from my point of view, $o(x^n)' = o(x^{n-1})$ requires that (i) underlying $\epsilon$ is derivable and (ii) $x\epsilon'(x) \to 0$.

These are two strong conditions that might explain why such a situation is rather rare.